# Why is there another post request after submitting a form?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to create a form where users will have to enter their email to get notified in the future. After successfully submitting the form I get a post call that refreshes the page that the form is in:

```
[07/Dec/2017 01:22:41] "POST /notify-email/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21
[07/Dec/2017 01:22:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 23030
```

Below is the relevant code:

**views.py**

```
def add_notify_email(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = NotifyEmailForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"status": "error"})
        else:
            form = NotifyEmailForm()
        return render(request, "landing/home.html", {"form": form})
```

**html**

```
<form class="form" onsubmit="addNotifyEmailInHero()" method="POST" id="notify_email_form_in_hero">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group" id="email_input_in_hero">
                <div class="input-group-addon" id="coming_soon_email_icon_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="email_icon_in_hero"></i></div>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode === 13){addNotifyEmailInHero()}" placeholder="If you want to get notified when we go live, please enter your email...." maxlength="255" required id="id_email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" id="notify_email_button_in_hero">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="submit_notify_email_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-bell nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notify Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="coming_soon.js"></script>
```

**coming_soon.js**

```
function addNotifyEmailInHero(e){
        var notifyEmailForm = $("#notify_email_form_in_hero");
        var thanksModal = $("#thanks");

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/notify-email/add/',
        data: notifyEmailForm.serialize(),
        success: function(res){
                   alert(res.status);
                   if(res.status === "success") {                
                        thanksModal.modal('show');
                            }

                    else {$("#id_email").val("");
                          $("#id_email").attr("placeholder", "Please Enter A Valid Email Address");
                            }
        }
    })}
```

**What I think is happening:**

When you click the button or press enter the form gets "submitted", that means the `onsubmit` function runs. Specifically, in the js script, you get the form and the modal, then there is an ajax post request with the data from the form to `/notify-email/add/`.

Based on the `urls.py`, `/notify-email/add/` is connected to the `add_notify_email` functional view in `views.py`. This function checks if it is a post request and if the form is valid it saves the data to the database and returns a json response, if the form is not valid it returns also a json response.

If the request is not a post request it renders the specified template.

If `add_notify_email` returns a json response that gets handled by the js function in `coming_soon.js`.

That's my understanding of what really is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an onsubmit handler that ultimately makes an AJAX call to /notify-email/add/, and then the form is submitted to its own handler, which is / because you did not specify a handler.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by form's own handler ?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou: When you submit a form, its contents are sent to the URL that is specified in the <form>'s "action" attribute (either as a POST or GET request). If "action" is not specified, the default URL is /.

Comment: If I add an action to the form like below:
    ```<form action="{% url "notif:notify_email_add" %}" onsubmit="addNotifyEmailInHero()" method="POST" id="notify_email_form_in_hero"> ```
I get the json response back for example {"status": "success"}

Comment: @GiannisIordanou: You have to suppress the normal form behavior in the onSubmit function, which I *think* you can do by having it return `false`.

Comment: I am not even sure if onsubmit is appropriate for what I want to do. I wanted to run ```addNotifyEmailInHero``` when either enter was pressed or the button was clicked.